# Can break the isomorphism between 2 semi-direct products componentwisely?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

Consider the isomorphism $$\begin{align*}
\psi : G \rtimes_{\phi_{1}} H \to G \rtimes _{\phi_{2}} H
\end{align*}$$ where $G \rtimes_{\phi_{i}} H$ is the semi-direct product of $G$ and $H$ with homomorphism $\phi_{i}: H \to \text{Aut}(G)$ .

Then can I have $\psi =(f, \pi)$ where $f \in \text{Aut}(G)$ and $\pi \in \text{Aut}(H)$ such that $$\begin{align*}
\psi(g,h) = (f(g),\pi(h))
\end{align*}$$ That is, can I break down $\psi$ componentwisely?

Comment: No, see for instance $\psi:\Bbb F_3\times\Bbb F_3\to \Bbb F_3\times\Bbb F_3$, $\psi(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$